# Stored procedure to constantly check table for records and process them

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, infinite-loop

We have a process that is causing dirty read errors. So, I was thinking of redesigning it as a queue with a single process to go through the queue.

My idea was to create a table that various processes could insert into. Then, one process actually processes the records in the table. But, we need real-time results from the processing method. So, while I was thinking of scheduling it to run every couple of seconds, that may not be fast enough. I don't want a user waiting several seconds for a result.

Essentially, I was thinking of using an infinite loop so that one stored procedure is constantly running, and that stored procedure creates transactions to perform updates.

It could be something like:

```
WHILE 1=1
BEGIN
    --Check for new records
    IF NewRecordsExist
    BEGIN
        --Mark new records as "in process"
        BEGIN TRANSACTION

            --Process records
            --If errors, Rollback
            --Otherwise Commit transaction
    END
END
```

But, I don't want SQL Server to get overburdened by this one method. Basically, I want this running in the background all the time, not eating up processor power. Unless there is a lot for it to do. Then, I want it doing its work. Is there a better design pattern for this? Are stored procedures with infinite loops thread-safe? I use this pattern all the time in Windows Processes, but this particular task is not appropriate for a Windows Process.

Update: We have transaction locking set. That is not the issue. We are trying to set aside items that are reserved for orders. So, we have a stored procedure start a transaction, check what is available, and then update the table to mark what is reserved.

The problem is that when two different users attempt to reserve the same product at the same time, the first process checks availability, finds product available, then start to reserve it. But, the second process cannot see what the first process is doing (we have transaction locking set), so it has no idea that another process is trying to reserve the items. It sees the items as still available and also goes to reserve them.

We considered application locking, but we are worried about waits, delays, etc. So, another solution we came up with is one process that handles reservations in a queue. It is first come first serve. Only one process will ever be reading the queue at a time. Different processes can add to the queue, but we no longer need to worry about two processes trying to reserve the same product at the same time. Only one process will be doing the reservations. I was hoping to do this all in SQL, but that may not be possible.

Comment: Recommend adding a "sql-server" tag for greater visibility among followers of that tag. I expect the consensus would be "no" t using a busy-waiting loop. As to the solution to your problem, I suggest backtracking to the source. Why are you getting dirty reads? Are you running queries with NOLOCK or READ UNCOMMITTED? Don't. Do you have data consisting of multiple records across multiple tables that are read before being fully written?  Use transactions. Figure out what is breaking ACID and try to fix that first. If unable, you probably need to provide more details to get a meaningful answer..

Comment: @TN Thank you for commenting. I added more details. Transaction locking is insufficient. The next step might either adding application locking or a queue. Or another solution we have not yet considered

Comment: Don't build queues in tables. SQL Server has [Service Broker](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-service-broker) specifically to avoid most of the pitfalls that happen if you reinvent the wheel (though not precisely all of them). The `WAITFOR` statement and internal activation (using stored procedures to process messages) solve the busy waiting problem.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Using the Service Broker sounds like exactly what I want. Could you make that an answer and I will mark it as the answer?

Comment: Sounds like you need to quickly lock certain data early in your transaction. Recommend looking at SELECTS with options UPDLOCK, ROWLOCK, and/or HOLDLOCK AND review isolation levels such as REPEATABLE READ and SERALIZABLE. These can lock rows and/or certain DML operations for the entire transaction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Disclaimer: This may be an option, but the recommendations for using a Service Broker to serialize requests are likely the better solutions.*

If you can't use a transaction, but need your your stored procedure to return an immediate result, there are ways to safely update a record in a single statement.

```
DECLARE @ProductId INT = 123
DECLARE @Quantity INT = 5

UPDATE Inventory
SET Available = Available - @Quantity
WHERE ProductId = @ProductId
AND Available >= @Quantity

IF @@ROW_COUNT > 0
BEGIN
  -- Success
END
```

Under the covers, there is still a transaction occurring accompanied by a lock, but it just covers this one statement.

If you need to update multiple records (reserve multiple product IDs) in one statement, you can use the OUTPUT clause to capture which records were successfully updated, which you can then compare with the original request.

```
DECLARE @Request TABLE (ProductId INT, Quantity INT)
DECLARE @Result TABLE (ProductId INT, Quantity INT)
INSERT @Request VALUES (123, 5), (456, 1)

UPDATE I
SET Available = Available - R.Quantity
OUTPUT R.ProductId, R.Quantity INTO @Result
FROM @Request R
JOIN Inventory I
    ON I.ProductId = R.ProductId
    AND I.Available >= R.@Quantity

IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @Request) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @Result)
BEGIN
    -- Success
END
ELSE BEGIN
    -- Partial or fail. Need to undo those that may have been updated.
END
```

In any case, you need to thoroughly think through your error handling and undo scenarios.

If you store reservations separate from inventory and define "Available" as "Inventory.OnHand - SUM(Reserved.Quantity)", this approach is not an option.

(Comments as to why this a bad approach will likely follow.)

Comment: I did pitch this as a bad possibility already :) no one voted to try it, lol.

Comment: Aside: A curious bit of [`update`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) syntax allows capturing _before_ and _after_ values in variables for a _single row_ operation: `update set @Before = Available, @After = Available -= R.Quantity from ... ;`. It may not be the right answer here, but it's a handy feature to know about.

Comment: I actually found an idea that works pretty well. I just need to trigger transaction locking earlier in the transaction. So, if I create a dummy update (Update sometable set somedata=somedata where id = (Select min(id) from sometable)) at the beginning of the transaction, it locks the transaction early enough to avoid the problem without worrying about the service broker.